# One-word cryptic clue with an one-letter answer

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, cryptic-clues

> **Death. (1)**

The rest of the word is —

> I'm giving a lift, but I'm not gonna offer any tea.

Comment: Did you mean one-letter answer? That's what **(1)** usually means.

Comment: @boboquack Yes, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Are you sure this is a cryptic clue? Cryptic clues have definition and wordplay in them.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is:

> E

Because

> (the end, i.e. the end of the word "the")

Comment: The answer is right, but the way you solved it isn't quite right. Death is the end of LIFE.

Comment: DEATH = end of LIFE

Comment: That's why, I have "the rest" which yields LIF. When you take away E from LIFE, LIF remains.

Comment: @RupertMorrish I have reconsidered my earlier opinion, and you are correct. I have removed my comments.